# Where do I put session start code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am using MVC, C#, LINQ, Entity

I need to put code for gathering active directory information every time a user visits a page.  I need access to this code on any page they could visit to display there name.

Where do I put code that would go in web forms session_start for MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put Session_Start in global.asax same as in web forms. Global.asax is part of asp.net framework. It is not exclusive for web forms.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  Didn't know it was possible to be the same.